# React Http post request to backend nodejs is pending

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a signup backend in nodejs and frontend in nextjs/reactjs

I see my http post request showing "Pending". No error message
[image]

[image]

The pending error is pointing to the fetch call here

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {API} from '../config';

export const signup = (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, { ----- Pending pointing here
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })

    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

config.js code

```js
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig();

export const API = publicRuntimeConfig.PRODUCTION
 ? publicRuntimeConfig.API_PRODUCTION
 : publicRuntimeConfig.API_DEVELOPMENT;
```

Signup code in Nextjs

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.table({firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, password, confirmpassword,howdidyouknowaboutus, error, loading, message, showForm});
        setValues({...values, loading: true, error: false});
        const user = {firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, password, confirmpassword,howdidyouknowaboutus};

        signup(user)
        .then(data => {
            
            if(data.error){
                setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false });
            }else{
                setValues({
                    firstname: '', 
                    lastname: '', 
                    email: '', 
                    phonenumber: '', 
                    password: '', 
                    confirmpassword: '',
                    howdidyouknowaboutus: '', 
                    error: '', 
                    loading: false, 
                    message: data.message, 
                    showForm: false
                });
            }
            console.log(data);
        });

    };
```

what is causing this pending? No error in the console.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe that problem is `headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },`. you try like this `headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },`

Comment: The same pending status. In postman, the http requests works fine

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `API` host is different to the host your nextjs app is running on? If so, it could potentially be an issue with the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) implementation on your `/signup` endpoint. Additionally, you may also need to explicitly allow certain request headers like `Accept` and `Content-Type`.

Not sure how the `/signup` endpoint is implemented but you'll need to set the following response headers.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
```

You can also set specific values to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` if you'd rather not set it to a wildcard `*` value like this.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://somehost.com"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding below resolve the issue. It was actually blocked by CORS

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
})

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be great if you could accept my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use **cors** package in node

install the package if you are using npm

```
npm install cors
```

then use the cors in app.use

```
app.use(cors());
```